# Find equation of tangent line, higher order function

Tags: calculus

I'm quite confused about this, I know for example how to find an equation of the tangent line to $y= x^2 + 1$ at $x = 1$, by applying the wel known formula $$m_{tan} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$.

I see how the theory arrives at this by drawing secant lines from P to some point Q, ever closer to P. And eventually making the difference come very close to 0.

So, basically I differentiate $y$ to get the slope. But I don't see how this applies to say: $f(x) = x^5 - 3x^2 + 3$ at $a = -1$. When I differentiate this function I end up with: $f'(x) = 5x^4 - 6x$, now what does this tell me about the slope? Somehow I'm not making the conceptual leap here and it's really bugging me out.

Plugging the whole shembang in got me nowhere (and seems way too tedious for this)

$$m_{tan} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(-1 + h)^5 - 3(-1 + h)^2 + 3}{h}$$, expanding this, et cetera....

So how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion. You said you found
$$f'(x)=5x^4-6x$$
Obviously, this is a function of the variable x. So what does this have to do with slope? Well, when you take the derivative, what you get is a *formula for computing the slope at any point x*. To find the slope at a particular point, say at $-1$, you need to plug in $x=-1$ in your formula above. Then you'd find
$$f'(-1)=5(-1)^4-6(-1)=11$$
and so the tangent line at this point has a slope of eleven.

As a side note, you could also figure this out by expanding the limit directly, as you attempted to do. The only problem with your attempt is that what you wrote down above is
$$\lim\frac{f(x+h)}{h}$$ and not $$\lim\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Answer (score 1):

That's  very simple: there's a formula for the tangent $(x_0,f(x_0))$: it's the polynomial part of *Taylor's formula* at order $1$:
$$y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

So here, for $f'x)=x^5-3x^2+3$ and $x_0=1$, you get $f'(-1)=11$, $f(-1)=-1$, so the tangent has equation:
$$y=-1+11(x+1)=11x+10.$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative continues to give you information about the slope of the function $f$ in point $x_0$, but you should look at it "near" the point $x_0$ ignoring what happens around.

In your case: $f(x) = x^5-3x^2+3$ implies $f'(x) = 5x^4-6x$. This tells you that the slope of $f(x)$ in point $x$ is $f'(x)$ if you look at it close enough to ignore what happens in surrounding. In particular for $x_0=-1$ holds $f'(x_0) = -1$ and that is the slope in point $x_0$ and "near".